# Oracle XPath: getting inner text

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath

My following query works well, but I can't seem to get the inner text on the option nodes for the life of me. How do I get required, received, archived or rejected to show up in the table as well? I've tried using $i/text(), $i/., etc. Thoughts?

```
select
  x."LABEL",
  x."NAME",
  x."THE_VAL"
FROM
  XMLTABLE(
    'for $i in /metadata/fields/field/option
      return element r{
        $i/@value,
        $i/../@label,
        $i/../@name
      }'
       PASSING xmltype(
     '<metadata>
    <fields>
     <field name="cusRc01" label="Capillary Pressure - MICP">
      <option value="1">Required</option>
      <option value="2">Received</option>
      <option value="3">Archived</option>
      <option value="4">Rejected</option>
      <option value="5">N/A</option>
    </field>
    <field name="cusRc02" label="Fluid Sensitivity">
      <option value="1">Required</option>
      <option value="2">Received</option>
      <option value="3">Archived</option>
      <option value="4">Rejected</option>
      <option value="5">N/A</option>
    </field>
    </fields>
    </metadata>')
       COLUMNS 
        --val_label VARCHAR(32) PATH 'option',
        the_val INTEGER PATH '@value',
        name VARCHAR(32) PATH '@name',
        label VARCHAR(32) PATH '@label') x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the `option` element contents (obtained with`text()`) into an attribute of your `r` element:

```
select
  x."VAL_LABEL",
  x."LABEL",
  x."NAME",
  x."THE_VAL"
FROM
  XMLTABLE(
    'for $i in /metadata/fields/field/option
      return element r{
        attribute val_label {$i/text()},
        $i/@value,
        $i/../@label,
        $i/../@name
      }'
       PASSING xmltype(
     '<metadata>
...
    </metadata>')
       COLUMNS 
        val_label VARCHAR(32) PATH '@val_label',
        the_val INTEGER PATH '@value',
        name VARCHAR(32) PATH '@name',
        label VARCHAR(32) PATH '@label') x;
```

Which gets:

```
VAL_LABEL                        LABEL                            NAME                                THE_VAL
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- ----------
Required                         Capillary Pressure - MICP        cusRc01                                   1
Received                         Capillary Pressure - MICP        cusRc01                                   2
Archived                         Capillary Pressure - MICP        cusRc01                                   3
Rejected                         Capillary Pressure - MICP        cusRc01                                   4
N/A                              Capillary Pressure - MICP        cusRc01                                   5
Required                         Fluid Sensitivity                cusRc02                                   1
Received                         Fluid Sensitivity                cusRc02                                   2
Archived                         Fluid Sensitivity                cusRc02                                   3
Rejected                         Fluid Sensitivity                cusRc02                                   4
N/A                              Fluid Sensitivity                cusRc02                                   5

 10 rows selected
```

You could also include the node as the last part of the element:

```
    'for $i in /metadata/fields/field/option
      return element r{
        $i/@value,
        $i/../@label,
        $i/../@name,
        $i/node()
      }'
```

... and then use @gmiley's dot notation:

```
       COLUMNS 
        val_label VARCHAR(32) PATH '.',
        the_val INTEGER PATH '@value',
        name VARCHAR(32) PATH '@name',
        label VARCHAR(32) PATH '@label') x;
```

... which gives the same output. Note that the node has to be the last thing in the element call, after all the attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the last bit for your columns definition to this:

```
   COLUMNS 
    val_label VARCHAR(32) PATH '.',
    the_val INTEGER PATH '@value',
    name VARCHAR(32) PATH '@name',
    label VARCHAR(32) PATH '@label') x;
```

You are already selecting `option` so you would be selecting `option/option` the way you had it before.

Comment: @slothario - you need the `element r{}` constructor to supply the option node's text too; with the `'.'` path you can include it as the element content, rather than an attribute. (I updated my answer to demo that approach).